# How to send image file via Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data, alamofire

I want to send an image to the server and I'm using this code:

```
Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            "https://api.mysite.com/image",
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                if let _ = image {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }                      
                }
            }, encodingCompletion: {
                encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .Success:
                            debugPrint(response)
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }

                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
```

but in response I get:

```
[Result]: SUCCESS: (
"",
    {
    file =         {
        error = 1;
        name = "file.png";
        size = 0;
        "tmp_name" = "";
        type = "";
    };
```

so my file is not sending to the server. What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: Try changing to `fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg"` also try getting a more descriptive error back from your server. Your code looks correct to send to the server, so issue might actually be server side.

Comment: no, the same result. In the server side all right =/

Comment: Can anyone offer something?

Comment: How do you know the server is correct?

Comment: because I checked it via the POSTman app and it returns me correct values @sbarow

Comment: Put an else statement after `if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0) {}` and ensure the `imageData` is getting appended to the form body.

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageData = UIPNGRepresentation(image)!

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
  debugPrint(response) 
}
```

from:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data

Comment: Where can we specify the name of file?